# Tabbar controller, pulling data by selecting a different tab

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I need help with pulling data from a textfield in Xcode. Not pushing data through.
For example, I have a tabbar controller which has two tabs. Tab1, and Tab2.

- **Tab1** contains a textfield.
- **Tab2** contains a Label.

Is it possible to type something in textField in the Tab1, and when pressing tab2, have that text automatically appear in the label in Tab2?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple class like "Data" that inherits NSObjects. Then add properties that store that data (don't forget to synthesize them). Add that class to both of your tabs' view controllers. Then pass around that data in the properties.

Comment: Thank you for that.. I think I'll use that one. I was trying to avoid doing that but that seems like the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are a few different ways to pass data between view controllers. You can post an NSNotification, you could save the value to NSUserDefaults, you could use a delegate. It would really depend on how much data you plan on passing from one view controller to another. I would probably use a delegate in this case.